# Number picker numeric keyboard and next button

Tags: java, android, xml, keyboard

I have three number pickers. One for hours, minutes and seconds. When I'm opening the soft keyboard, the hours opens the qwerty keyboard, while the minutes and seconds pickers opens the numeric keyboard. I'm looking for something like
    android:inputType="number"
That we have in an EditText.
This is how I made the numberPickers.

```
    npHour = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerHours);
    npMin = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerMinutes);
    npSec = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPickerSeconds);
    String[] hours = new String[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++)
           hours[i] = Integer.toString(i);

    npHour.setMinValue(0);
    npHour.setMaxValue(99);
    npHour.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    npHour.setDisplayedValues(hours);

    String[] minSec = new String[60];
    for(int i = 0; i < minSec.length; i++)
           minSec[i] = Integer.toString(i);

    npMin.setMinValue(0);
    npMin.setMaxValue(59);
    npSec.setMinValue(0);
    npSec.setMaxValue(59);
```

Also the keyboard has the "done" button rather than the "next" button you will naturally want in the hours and minutes number pickers. How could I do this? Tried descendantFocusability and nextFocus in XML, neither worked.

Comment: Can you post code, image or whatever to see what happens?

Comment: Added the java code of the pickers.

Comment: See if this answer helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794265/restricting-android-numberpicker-to-numeric-keyboard-for-numeric-input-not-alph

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens if a user taps into the number picker and it also happens in the time picker (the circular/round one)